# From Advanced Custom Field's checkbox, I need to add something as checked in the checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages, custom-fields

this is what my code looks like:
Any help will be very appreciable.

```
    <?php
        $btn = get_field('line_btn');
        if( $btn && in_array('study', $btn ) ) { 
          echo 'study';       // working well
        }
        elseif( $btn && in_array('help', $btn ) ) { 
          echo 'help';        // working well
        }
        elseif( $btn && in_array('study', 'help', $btn) ) { 
          echo 'both selected';     // not working
        }
      ?>
```

Comment: Your question lacks necessary details. Please read [mre]

Comment: You should tell us what is actually causing you problems. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would also help a great deal.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In Advanced Custom FIelds I created a **checkbox** with two options. lets say **'study'** and **'help'**. So if the admin selects _'study'_, then it should return certain code like _<div class="study">....</div>_. And if the admin selects _'help'_, then it should return certain code like _<div class="help">.....</div>_. And lastly if admin selects **both** then it should return both like _<div class="study">.....</div><div class="help">....</div>_.

My code works well for returning **separate value**. But it is not working well if the admin selects **both options**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in_array()` only checks for one value in the array and you are trying to pass in two. You would have to us two separate `in_array()` functions in the `elseif`.

```
<?php
        $btn = get_field('line_btn');
        if( $btn && in_array('study', $btn ) ) { 
          echo 'study';       // working well
        }
        elseif( $btn && in_array('help', $btn ) ) { 
          echo 'help';        // working well
        }
        elseif( $btn && in_array('study', $btn) && in_array( 'help', $btn ) { 
          echo 'both selected';
        }
      ?>
```

Comment: **Thanks a lot** @JayDev95
Is there a way that I can shorten the code like:
   `<?php
      $btn = get_field('line_btn');
      if( $btn && in_array('study', $btn) && in_array( 'help', $btn ) { 
          if( $btn && in_array('study', $btn ) ) { 
            echo 'study';       // working well
          }
          elseif( $btn && in_array('help', $btn ) ) { 
            echo 'help';        // working well
          }
      }
    ?>`

Comment: @Shin-chyan That logic wouldn't work for what you are looking for. If you are looking to make the template file neater, you have different options. You can either place this in a function and call that function, or put a custom action hook where you need this to show and then add that function to that action hook.

Comment: Thank you. But I am looking for another way other than writing that in a function

Comment: @Shin-chyan You can create a shortcode if that'll work better for you.